# Seleccionar un editbox y escribir con un teclado en html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día, tengo un formulario y estoy haciendo un **teclado virtual** que al darle click a las teclas llene las cajas de texto del formulario, pero no se como hacer para que llene solo la que está seleccionada.

A continuación todo el código de lo que tengo hasta ahora, ejecútenlo y verán lo que pasa, entenderán que es lo que quiero hacer.
En simples palabras quiero que escriba en la caja de texto que yo seleccione con el mouse.

```js
function str1(valor){
     var elemento=document.getElementById("Editbox1");
     var value=elemento.value;
     elemento.value=value+valor; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tarea 4, Dany</title>
    <link href="Untitled1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("a[href*='#intro']").click(function(event)
       {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('#intro').offset().top }, 600, 'easeOutQuad');
       });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #D8BFD8">
    <div id="intro" style="position:relative;text-align:center;width:100%;height:100%;float:left;display:block;z-index:46;">
    <div id="intro-overlay"></div>
    <div id="intro_Container" style="width:970px;position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:left;">
    <div id="wb_Shape1" style="position:absolute;left:220px;top:4px;width:531px;height:405px;z-index:0;">
    <img src="images/img0001.png" id="Shape1" alt="" style="width:531px;height:405px;"></div>
    <div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:246px;top:32px;width:195px;height:19px;z-index:1;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;"><strong>Datos del Comprobador</strong></span></div>
    <div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:334px;top:87px;width:59px;height:17px;z-index:2;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Nombre</span></div>
    <div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:334px;top:121px;width:58px;height:17px;z-index:3;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Email</span></div>
    <div id="wb_Text4" style="position:absolute;left:334px;top:184px;width:70px;height:17px;z-index:4;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Teléfono</span></div>
    <div id="wb_Text5" style="position:absolute;left:334px;top:152px;width:46px;height:17px;z-index:5;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">País</span></div>
    <input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:82px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:6;" name="Editbox1" value=""  spellcheck="false">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:115px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:7;" name="Editbox2" value="" spellcheck="false">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox3" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:147px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:8;" name="Editbox3" value="" spellcheck="false">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox4" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:179px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:9;" name="Editbox4" value="" spellcheck="false">
    <div id="wb_Text6" style="position:absolute;left:246px;top:246px;width:300px;height:19px;z-index:10;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;"><strong>Datos de la Tarjeta de crédito o débito</strong></span></div>
    <textarea name="TextArea1" id="TextArea1" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:281px;width:227px;height:10px;z-index:11;" rows="1" cols="35" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="Editbox5" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:307px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:12;" name="Editbox5" value="" spellcheck="false">
    <div id="wb_Shape2" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:423px;width:953px;height:214px;z-index:13;">
    <img src="images/img0002.png" id="Shape2" alt="" style="width:953px;height:214px;"></div>
    
    <input type="button" id="Button1" name="" value="a" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
    style="position:absolute;left:29px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:14;" >
    
    <input type="button" id="Button2" name="" value="b"
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:111px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:15;">
    
    <input type="button" id="Button3" name="" value="c"
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:198px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:16;">
    
    <input type="button" id="Button4" name="" value="d" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:284px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:17;">
    
    <input type="button" id="Button5" name="" value="e" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:369px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:18;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button6" name="" value="f" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:453px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:19;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button7" name="" value="g" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:537px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:20;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button8" name="" value="h"
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:621px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:21;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button9" name="" value="i" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:708px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:22;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button10" name="" value="j"
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
          style="position:absolute;left:794px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:23;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button11" name="" value="k"
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:878px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:24;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button13" name="" value="l" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:29px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:25;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button14" name="" value="m" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:111px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:26;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button15" name="" value="n" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:197px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:27;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button16" name="" value="o" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:284px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:28;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button17" name="" value="p" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:369px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:29;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button18" name="" value="q"
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:453px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:30;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button19" name="" value="r" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:537px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:31;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button20" name="" value="s" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:621px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:32;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button21" name="" value="t" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:708px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:33;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button22" name="" value="u" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:794px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:34;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button23" name="" value="v" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:878px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:35;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button24" name="" value="w" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:29px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:36;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button25" name="" value="x" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:111px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:37;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button26" name="" value="y" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:197px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:38;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button27" name="" value="z" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:284px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:39;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button50" name="" value="--" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:368px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:50;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button28" name="" value="@" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:453px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:40;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button29" name="" value="-" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:537px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:41;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button30" name="" value="_" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
            style="position:absolute;left:621px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:42;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button31" name="" value="1" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:708px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:43;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button32" name="" value="2" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:794px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:44;">
    
    <input type="submit" id="Button33" name="" value="3" 
           onclick="str1(this.value);"
           style="position:absolute;left:878px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:45;">
    
    </div>
    </div>
         
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te incluyo otra forma de resolver el problema del foco en tu programa, aqui solamente tiene que incluir el codigo en javascript y lo demas queda como esta. en este codigo se toma como campo inicial el EditBox1, luego se tiene un for que creara una grupo del  listener para los campos que son de etiqueta input, seguidamente con el if() se filtra solo los campos de entrada de tipo text los cuales van a tomar el id correspondiente. mas abajo se captura el evento para el TextArea1 que tambien esta en el formulario.

Otra cosa que tiene el codigo es que vas a tener el borde de foco en el campo seleccionado, con lo cual sabras en que input esta seleccionado.

adjunto el codigo.

```js
        // captura el id el campo seleccionado
        var campoTexto = "Editbox1"; // por defecto var global
        entradas = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); // toma el grupo de input
        // genere un listening para el grupo de input
        for (var i = 0; i < entradas.length; i++) {
            entradas[i].addEventListener('click',function (evt) {        
                       // filtra solo los input text
                       if (evt.target.type=='text') { 
                            campoTexto = evt.target.id   // optiene el id
                       } 
            });
        }
        // para el text area 
        document.getElementById("TextArea1").addEventListener('click',function (evt) {        
                            campoTexto = evt.target.id   // optiene el id
                       });

        function str1(valor){
            var elemento=document.getElementById(campoTexto);    
            document.getElementById(campoTexto).focus(); // foco del campo
            var value=elemento.value;
            elemento.value=value+valor; 
       }
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #D8BFD8">
<div id="intro" style="position:relative;text-align:center;width:100%;height:100%;float:left;display:block;z-index:46;">
<div id="intro-overlay"></div>
<div id="intro_Container" style="width:970px;position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:left;">
<div id="wb_Shape1" style="position:absolute;left:220px;top:4px;width:531px;height:405px;z-index:0;">
<img src="images/img0001.png" id="Shape1" alt="" style="width:531px;height:405px;"></div>
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:246px;top:32px;width:195px;height:19px;z-index:1;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;"><strong>Datos del Comprobador</strong></span></div>
<div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:334px;top:87px;width:59px;height:17px;z-index:2;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Nombre</span></div>
<div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:334px;top:121px;width:58px;height:17px;z-index:3;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Email</span></div>
<div id="wb_Text4" style="position:absolute;left:334px;top:184px;width:70px;height:17px;z-index:4;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Teléfono</span></div>
<div id="wb_Text5" style="position:absolute;left:334px;top:152px;width:46px;height:17px;z-index:5;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">País</span></div>
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:82px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:6;" name="Editbox1" value=""  spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:115px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:7;" name="Editbox2" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" id="Editbox3" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:147px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:8;" name="Editbox3" value="" spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" id="Editbox4" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:179px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:9;" name="Editbox4" value="" spellcheck="false">
<div id="wb_Text6" style="position:absolute;left:246px;top:246px;width:300px;height:19px;z-index:10;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;"><strong>Datos de la Tarjeta de crédito o débito</strong></span></div>
<textarea name="TextArea1" id="TextArea1" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:281px;width:227px;height:10px;z-index:11;" rows="1" cols="35" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="Editbox5" style="position:absolute;left:451px;top:307px;width:227px;height:16px;z-index:12;" name="Editbox5" value="" spellcheck="false">
<div id="wb_Shape2" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:423px;width:953px;height:214px;z-index:13;">
<img src="images/img0002.png" id="Shape2" alt="" style="width:953px;height:214px;"></div>

<input type="button" id="Button1" name="" value="a" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
style="position:absolute;left:29px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:14;" >

<input type="button" id="Button2" name="" value="b"
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:111px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:15;">

<input type="button" id="Button3" name="" value="c"
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:198px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:16;">

<input type="button" id="Button4" name="" value="d" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:284px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:17;">

<input type="button" id="Button5" name="" value="e" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:369px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:18;">

<input type="submit" id="Button6" name="" value="f" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:453px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:19;">

<input type="submit" id="Button7" name="" value="g" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:537px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:20;">

<input type="submit" id="Button8" name="" value="h"
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:621px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:21;">

<input type="submit" id="Button9" name="" value="i" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:708px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:22;">

<input type="submit" id="Button10" name="" value="j"
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
      style="position:absolute;left:794px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:23;">

<input type="submit" id="Button11" name="" value="k"
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:878px;top:440px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:24;">

<input type="submit" id="Button13" name="" value="l" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:29px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:25;">

<input type="submit" id="Button14" name="" value="m" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:111px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:26;">

<input type="submit" id="Button15" name="" value="n" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:197px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:27;">

<input type="submit" id="Button16" name="" value="o" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:284px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:28;">

<input type="submit" id="Button17" name="" value="p" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:369px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:29;">

<input type="submit" id="Button18" name="" value="q"
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:453px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:30;">

<input type="submit" id="Button19" name="" value="r" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:537px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:31;">

<input type="submit" id="Button20" name="" value="s" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:621px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:32;">

<input type="submit" id="Button21" name="" value="t" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:708px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:33;">

<input type="submit" id="Button22" name="" value="u" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:794px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:34;">

<input type="submit" id="Button23" name="" value="v" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:878px;top:504px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:35;">

<input type="submit" id="Button24" name="" value="w" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:29px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:36;">

<input type="submit" id="Button25" name="" value="x" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:111px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:37;">

<input type="submit" id="Button26" name="" value="y" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:197px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:38;">

<input type="submit" id="Button27" name="" value="z" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:284px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:39;">

<input type="submit" id="Button50" name="" value="--" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:368px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:50;">

<input type="submit" id="Button28" name="" value="@" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:453px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:40;">

<input type="submit" id="Button29" name="" value="-" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:537px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:41;">

<input type="submit" id="Button30" name="" value="_" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
        style="position:absolute;left:621px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:42;">

<input type="submit" id="Button31" name="" value="1" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:708px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:43;">

<input type="submit" id="Button32" name="" value="2" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:794px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:44;">

<input type="submit" id="Button33" name="" value="3" 
       onclick="str1(this.value);"
       style="position:absolute;left:878px;top:570px;width:65px;height:56px;z-index:45;">

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Mil gracias, sin duda alguna es lo que estaba buscando